# What to use to install a simple drop ceiling for home theater

Tags: ceiling, mount

Instead of drilling the concrete ceiling multiple times to support a motorized projector screen, a projector, and some lights (*either strips, or some panels for decoration*), I was thinking about creating a drop ceiling.

The benefit is that I can change layout of the items just by replacing the drop ceiling panel, leaving the original ceiling intact. The wires could also be hidden at the top (*between the original ceiling and the drop ceiling panel*).

I was thinking about four holes, one in each corner, with brackets that would support the drop ceiling. Note this is supported only by the ceiling, like an island, there will be no support from the walls.

The size of this drop ceiling I need to cover these items installed is 70 x 70 inches, an opening (*distance from ceiling to drop ceiling*) of about 4 inches (*this opening height can be different if needed*). The items would weight about 16 pounds (7 kgs) total (*not super heavy*).

Questions related to this:

- What to use for this drop ceiling? My initial thought would be a wood board painted. Are there other materials I should consider? I believe the lightest, but rigid enough to support the items, is best.
- What to use for the supporting brackets? Are they available to be purchased individually?

It seems to me this is something I can do myself, just need the support and install the board/panel, and then install the items (*projector, lights*) to the board.

Comment: What is the difference between drilling holes for the projector/screen and drilling holes for the drop ceiling? Just fewer holes?

Comment: @AlaskaMan It's very different! The drop ceiling would never require new holes. If things need to be rearranged (new projector for example, or a new mount, or new layout of the lights, etc.) I could just replace the drop ceiling and would have a brand new "ceiling" to drill new holes for the new tech. It's like having a replaceable ceiling whenever needed. I'm not a fan of patching and drilling new holes directly on the original ceiling.